# MySQL left join with LIMIT 1 not returning desired result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I am having trouble with a SQL query; I am trying to get the last service date of each 'asset'.

I am trying to use a left join with a subquery with a limit to 1.

Here are my tables:

lctn_test

```
testID, cleintID
1,      34
2,      34
```

srvc_test

```
srvcTestID, testID, serviceDate,            servicePassed
1,          1,      2018-05-19 03:23:53,    1
2,          1,      2018-05-19 11:46:49,    1
3,          2,      2018-05-19 11:47:24,    1
```

and here is what I have tried (as well as a few variations)

```
SELECT 
    lctn.testID AS assetID, lctn.ClientID, 
    srvc_test.serviceDate, srvc_test.servicePassed
FROM 
    lctn_test AS lctn
LEFT JOIN 
    srvc_test ON lctn.testID = (SELECT srvc_test.testID
                                FROM srvc_test
                                WHERE srvc_test.testID = lctn.testID
                                ORDER BY srvc_test.serviceDate DESC
                                LIMIT 1)
WHERE 
    lctn.ClientID = 34
ORDER BY 
    assetID
```

What I expected to get:

```
assetID,    ClientID,   serviceDate,            servicePassed
1,          34,         2018-05-19 11:46:49,    1
2,          34,         2018-05-19 11:47:24,    1
```

but this is what I actually get:

```
assetID,    ClientID,   serviceDate,            servicePassed
1,          34,         2018-05-19 03:23:53,    1
1,          34,         2018-05-19 11:46:49,    1
1,          34,         2018-05-19 11:47:24,    1
2,          34,         2018-05-19 03:23:53,    1
2,          34,         2018-05-19 11:46:49,    1
2,          34,         2018-05-19 11:47:24,    1
```

I am still learning SQL (mysql) and for the life of me I can't see the issue; I am betting it is a noob mistake but I just don't see it.

Comment: You should join using `srvcTestID` instead of `testID`.

Comment: What is an "asset"?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i cant join on srvcTestID as it is not a foreign key, the lctn_test table does not have a srvcTestID. unless i am missing your point.

Comment: @GordonLinoff an item i am recording, could be a car for example.

Comment: `... ON srvc_test.srvcTestID = (
    SELECT srvc_test.srvcTestID ... )`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel that is exactly it, you should make that a full answer, with an explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exactly one row per join you should use a UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) KEY of the joined table in the ON clause. That is probably `srvc_test.srvcTestID`.

```
SELECT lctn.testID AS assetID, lctn.ClientID, srvc_test.serviceDate, srvc_test.servicePassed
FROM lctn_test AS lctn
LEFT JOIN srvc_test ON srvc_test.srvcTestID = (
    SELECT srvc_test.srvcTestID
    FROM srvc_test
    WHERE srvc_test.testID = lctn.testID
    ORDER BY srvc_test.serviceDate DESC
    LIMIT 1)
WHERE lctn.ClientID = 34
ORDER BY assetID
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = (sub-query)`

You should have `a LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = (sub-query)`

```
SELECT lctn.testID AS assetID, lctn.ClientID, srvc_test.serviceDate, srvc_test.servicePassed
FROM lctn_test AS lctn
LEFT JOIN srvc_test ON srvc_test.srvcTestID = (
    SELECT srvc_test.srvcTestID
    FROM srvc_test
    WHERE srvc_test.testID = lctn.testID
    ORDER BY srvc_test.serviceDate DESC
    LIMIT 1)
WHERE lctn.ClientID = 34
ORDER BY assetID
```

Comment: this results in all 3 services being retrieved, when i only want the latest for each 'assetID'

Comment: nope, your edit works, i retract my earlier statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing the actual `join` condition:

```
SELECT lctn.testID AS assetID, lctn.ClientID, srvc_test.serviceDate, srvc_test.servicePassed
FROM lctn_test lctn LEFT JOIN
     srvc_test st
     ON st.testID = lctn.testID AND
        st.testID = (SELECT st2.testID
                     FROM srvc_test st2
                     WHERE st2.testID = st.testID
                     ORDER BY st.serviceDate DESC
                     LIMIT 1
                    )
WHERE lctn.ClientID = 34
ORDER BY assetID;
```

I switched the correlation conditions to be based on `srvc_test` rather than `lctn_test`.  This doesn't really make a difference.  I just find it simpler to be referring to a single table for this purpose.